# Inserting text through vim mapping is slow

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` I created the following mapping. Basically I want VIM to insert some text when pressing `<leader>c`.

The mapping is defined as follows:

```
map <leader>c iHELLO WORLD<Esc>;w<CR>
```

The second part of the map works (it exits insert mode correctly), but it takes about a second for it to actually go from normal mode to insert mode and insert the text.

I imagine this might be related to setting in my `.vimrc`. You can take a look at that [here](https://github.com/thejsj/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc).

Comment: What does `:verbose map <leader>c` give you? Once mapping or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have another mapping that shares a common prefix (`<leader>c`), and so Vim is waiting to see if you are going to type out any disambiguating characters before assuming you meant "just `<leader>c`".

You can avoid this by picking a non-ambiguous mapping, changing the other mapping, or reducing `'timeoutlen'` from its default value of 1000 (ms).

To find out what the conflicting mapping might be, try `:map <leader>c` and inspect the output.

Answer (score 1):

You must have multiple `<leader>c`-mappings. Vim has to wait to disambiguate for `timeoutlen` ms to see if you’re going to type `<leader>cx` (where `x` is anything`).

You can see your related mappings with `verbose map <leader>c`. Then either remove the others or extend yours to be something like `<leader>ch` (`h` as “Hello” mnemonic).